# Finding the critical points of $f(x,y,z) = x\ln{(x)} + y\ln{(y)} + t(1-x-y-z)\ln(1-x-y-z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The question I'm trying to do asks:

> Find the critical points of the function $f(x,y,z) = x\ln{(x)} + y\ln{(y)} + t(1-x-y-z)\ln(1-x-y-z)$ on the domain $E := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x > 0, y > 0, x + y + z < 1\}$, with $0 \ne t \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ is not a variable, but a parameter.

I've gone ahead and calculated the first derivatives of everything:

$f_x = \ln{(x)} + 1 - t\ln{(1-x-y-z)} - t$

$f_y = \ln{(y)} + 1 - t\ln{(1-x-y-z)} - t$

$f_z = -t\ln(1-x-y-z) - t$

To find the critical points, I know I need to look at $\nabla f = 0$. I feel like this might just be a hairy calculation-based question, but I really don't know how to find the critical points for this function. I can't seem to find a solution that satisfies the constraints given by the domain (i.e $x > 0, y > 0, x+y+z < 1$). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your third equation, we know that all critical points $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ will satisfy
\begin{equation*}
\log(1-x^*-y^*-z^*) = -1.
\end{equation*}
Substituting this result into your first expression we find
\begin{equation*}
0=\log(x^*) + 1 + t - t = \log(x^*) + 1,
\end{equation*}
so $x^* = 1/e$. Similarly for the second expression we also find that all critical points satisfy $y^*=1/e$. Finally, from the third equation we find that
\begin{equation*}
1-x^*-y^*-z^*=1/e,
\end{equation*}
so $z^* = 1-x^*-y^*-1/e = 1-1/e-1/e-1/e = 1-3/e$. Therefore, the only critical point is
\begin{equation*}
(x^*,y^*,z^*) = (1/e,1/e,1-3/e),
\end{equation*}
which satisfies the constraints you are given.